# AWS athena deep scan for JSON Data

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, jsonpath, trino

I am not able to query the nested keys with `..` operator which is supported by JSONPath in Athena.

```
WITH dataset AS (
   SELECT '{"name": "aa",
             "id":-100,
             "org": "engineering",
             "key":{"val":1000},
             "projects": [{"name":"project1", "completed":false},{"name":"project2", "completed":true}]}'
     AS blob1
)
-- This is not working
SELECT * FROM dataset where json_extract_scalar(blob1, '$..val') = '1000';

-- Working
SELECT * FROM dataset where json_extract_scalar(blob1, '$.key.val') = '1000';
```

Is there any alternative way by which I can query nested fields in Athena?

Comment: Great that you have a full repro, but still "This is not working" usually not that useful for those who are trying to help you with your issue so please try to share also exact error details next time.

Answer (score 1):

Athena/Presto json path support is not very great. You can work around that but it is quite messy involving casting your json to `MAP(VARCHAR, JSON)` and then working with resulting values:

```sql
WITH dataset AS (
    SELECT '{"name": "aa",
             "id":-100,
             "org": "engineering",
             "key":{"val":1000},
             "projects": [{"name":"project1", "completed":false},{"name":"project2", "completed":true}]}' AS blob1
)

SELECT *
FROM dataset
WHERE contains(
        transform(
            map_values(cast(json_parse(blob1) as MAP(VARCHAR, JSON))),
            j->try(json_extract_scalar(j, '$.val'))
        ),
        '1000'
    )
```